# How To Alias Model Inside Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular template, and I would like to reuse the template inside two different controllers. The issue is that both controllers require different ng-model names.

The template contains HTML like below, where the ng-model references are properties of "obj":

```
<input name="customer" ng-model="obj.customer" id="customer">
```

One of the controllers needs the ng-model names to be associated with "obj". This means the template is perfect as is.

The other controller needs the ng-model to be associated with, for the sake of simplicity, "obj1".

Is there a way to handle this in such a way that I could use the same HTML template? It seems a shame to have to duplicate the HTML just to change the ng-model name. I tried using ng-init, saying obj = obj1, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is where a directive helps.

Comment: @PSL could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: Create a directive with 2 way binding, So you could bind with any model as you need and the template becomes as reusable as a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with what @PSL commented about...

Directives in Angular allow for templates and code to be re-used elsewhere throughout your application. You can pass an angular directive some sort of model, and it behaves as its own controller and own scope, isolating it from the rest of your app.

Take for example you wish to have a list of user's and their information, you can create a directive and pass onto it data on which to act upon. Then you can repeat the process as many times as you like.

For more information and examples you can check out Angular's write up on Directives. [>> Directives guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

I'll also provide a short example directive below with your customer problem..
[>>plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ybpL84QSTBbnetjXY23?p=preview)

```
.directive('myCustomer', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
return {
  template: '<input name="customer" data-ng-model="customerInfo.name">',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    customerInfo: "="
  },
  controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.init = function(){
      console.log("i'm alive!");
    }
  }],
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, transclute, requires){
    scope.init();
  }
}
}])
```

Hope this helps!

-mbp